# Django websocket connection failure

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

Websocket is refusing to connect in my project and showing me this message

> (index):12 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/[object%20HTMLScriptElement]/' failed:

When entering the path http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/wilh/ where
(wilh) is just the name of the chat_room, it can be changed with any name, django should connect to websocket and show a starter message that is "hello, world!". but websocket is refusing to connect with that path

here is my project repo link : [Repository link](https://github.com/MustafaAlsadah/realtime-chat-app)

Comment: Please add more details on what you've tried, what's the issue, what you've tried so far to debug, where it's happening...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.